# How do I add support for multiple languages using (jQuery I18n Translation Plugin)?

Tags: jquery, internationalization

I am experimenting with "jQuery I18n Translation Plugin" and had couple of questions

- Does the browser know what language to use ? Does it do it   automatically when is use u18n?
- How can I use multiple languages say french and   spanish? so that it
  calls each one base on localization

http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2008/02/21/jquery-i18n-translation-plugin/

Here is my code below::

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    i18n_dict = { 
        "Example 1"  : "teiän veen",
        "Example 2"  : "tei'än ve'en",
        "Example 3"  : "teiä vede",
        "Example 4"  : "teirän veren",
        "Example 5"  : "teilän velen",
        "Example 6"  : "teijjän vejen",
        "Example 7"  : "teidän veden",
        "Example 8"  : "teitän veten",
        "Example 9"  : "teiðän veðen",
        "Example 10" : "teidhän vethen",
        "Dynamic Content" : "Your browser window is %s x %s",
        "Ordered Dynamic Content": "%2$s is the height of your browser window, and %1$s is the width."
    };

    $.i18n.setDictionary(i18n_dict);

        $('div#example1').text($.i18n._('Example 1'));
        $('div#example2').text($.i18n._('Example 2'));
        $('div#example3').text($.i18n._('Example 3'));
        $('div#example4').text($.i18n._('Example 4'));
        $('div#example5').text($.i18n._('Example 5'));
        $('div#example6').text($.i18n._('Example 6'));
        $('div#example7').text($.i18n._('Example 7'));
        $('div#example8').text($.i18n._('Example 8'));
        $('div#example9').text($.i18n._('Example 9'));
        $('div#example10').text($.i18n._('Example 10'));
        $('div#dynamic').text($.i18n._('Dynamic Content', [$(document).width(), $(document).height()]));
        $('div#orderedDynamic').text($.i18n._('Ordered Dynamic Content', [$(document).width(), $(document).height()]));

});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id='example1'>Example 1</div>
    <div id='example2'>Example 2</div>
    <div id='example3'>Example 3</div>
    <div id='example4'>Example 4</div>
    <div id='example5'>Example 5</div>
    <div id='example6'>Example 6</div>
    <div id='example7'>Example 7</div>
    <div id='example8'>Example 8</div>
    <div id='example9'>Example 9</div>
    <div id='example10'>Example 10</div>
    <div id='dynamic'>Dynamic Content</div>
    <div id='orderedDynamic'>Ordered Dynamic Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- navigator.language (Netscape - Browser Localization)
- navigator.browserLanguage (IE-Specific - Browser Localized Language)
- navigator.systemLanguage (IE-Specific - Windows OS - Localized Language)
- navigator.userLanguage

As a plugin, try using jQuery.i18n plugin, check:
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/

Example:
var lang = 'en';
var config = {
        name : 'Messages',
        path : '/my_application/i18n/',
        mode : 'both',
        language: lang,
                callback: function() {
                  //do sth
              }
    };

// reload configuration
jQuery.i18n.properties(config);

This snipplet will ask your application for files:
/my_application/i18n/Messages.properties
/my_application/i18n/Messages_en.properties
Providing you with internationalization for specified locale.
This will give you many languages to choose from.

Comment: There’s a nice tutorial here: https://dev.to/adrai/the-progressive-guide-to-jquery-internationalization-i18n-using-i18next-3dc3